# How to update a VERIFY_PASSWORD_FUNCTION in oracle for users to retain his password for 1 day at least before change/alter it

Tags: oracle, passwords, schema, verify

It a one of requirement where the client needs there Oracle users do not change his password very soon, so they need to retain at least one day before altering it. So it can not be changed on the same day, where we have to update VERIFY_PASSWORD_FUNCTION code to set a limit minimum password age 1 day.

Comment: This seems like a fake - or at least misguided - requirement. It's easy to think of reasons why a user might want or need to change their password soon after changing it. Why not let them?

Comment: No, I don't think its a fake, a client may have such a requirement in different cases.

Comment: So if a user's password is changed to something insecure, you want to ensure they keep their insecure password for at least 24 hours?

Comment: It's always strong, In this function, we've already set strong password scenarios with the logic of multiple special and alphanumeric characters, and 1-day password retain is add-on requirement, so we've modified the code in such way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Append Below Code in "VERIFY_PASSWORD_FUNCTION" Function:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SYS"."VERIFY_PASSWORD_FUNCTION" 
(username varchar2,
password varchar2,
old_password varchar2)
RETURN boolean IS
last_change sys.user$.ptime%type;
minimum_age number :=1;
userexist integer;
begin
-- Set minimum password age 
select count(*) into userexist from sys.user$ where name=username;
if (userexist != 0) then
    select ptime into last_change from sys.user$ where name=username;
    if sysdate - last_change < minimum_age then
        raise_application_error(-20010, 'Password changed too soon');
    END IF; 
end if;
end;
/
```

From the above code you have to append only variables and logic.

**Here is A Test Case:**

```
SQL> create user TEST11 identified by asdfhe#24HyrE profile USERS;

User Created.

SQL> alter user test11 identified by asdfhe#24HyrWW;
alter user test11 identified by asdfhe#24HyrWW
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28003: password verification for the specified password failed
ORA-20010: Password changed too soon

SQL> 

SQL> select name,ptime from user$ where name='TEST11';

NAME                           PTIME
------------------------------ ---------
TEST11                         08-NOV-18

SQL> update user$ set ptime='03-Nov-18' where name='TEST11';

1 row updated.

SQL> select name,ptime from user$ where name='TEST11';

NAME                           PTIME
------------------------------ ---------
TEST11                         03-NOV-18

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> alter user test11 identified by asdfhe#24HyrWW;

User altered.

SQL>
```

Since we can not change the password within same day so we've updated ptime value to verify and tried again to alter password for Test11 user.

Comment: It is very bad practice to update the SYS internal tables. Obviously this is just  a clever trick to test your code but don't do it in Production (or any other environment you care about) because you run the risk of invalidating your Oracle Support contract.

Comment: Yes true, we don't have to update the sys table but, sometimes we've a little different requirement by the time we can make the changes.